# SSH - Remote executing program from host failed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I need to run this command from Ubuntu machine: `ssh user@hostip "which mvn"` to show excutable path of Maven , but it show nothing

```
root@~: ssh user@hostip "which mvn"
root@~:
```

I check command `which mvn` on remote host it show me :

```
root@~: which mvn
/usr/share/mvn
root@~:
```

I try to sourcing `.bashrc` when excute ssh command but no luck:

```
root@~: ssh user@hostip ". ~/.bashrc;which mvn"
root@~:
```

In ./bashrc also have nothing about maven PATH configure

So , what i have to do ?

Comment: What's the output of ssh user@hostip "echo $PATH", `which` command search the executable file in folders specified by $PATH

Comment: @Cody you need single quotes on that or you'll get the local path.

Answer (score 0):

```
root@~: ssh user@hostip "which mvn"
```

When you run `ssh` and specify a command to invoke on the remote system, `ssh` by default doesn't allocate a PTY (pseudo-TTY) for the remote session. Shells like `bash` will detect that they're running without a TTY, and  this will alter how the shell process initializes itself.

In your case, whatever command adds "/usr/share" to your remote PATH is probably not running for non-interactive sessions (sessions without a TTY).
You can probably solve this by telling `ssh` to request a TTY for the remote session:

```
ssh -tt user@hostip "which mvn"
```

The `-t` option tells `ssh` to request a TTY for the remote session. This would cause your remote shell instance to initialize itself for an interactive session. Refer to the [ssh manual](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh) for details on the `-t` option.

If this doesn't solve the problem, you will need to find the point in your shell configuration files on the remote server (.bash_profile, .bashrc, etc.) where `/usr/share` is being added to your PATH, and make sure that step is performed for non-interactive sessions.